# x=600 y=1000 if x <= y is going to false?

Tags: jquery

What is the proper or the correct way? I'm confused about this. Can someone make it correct?

`3digit <= 4digit` is `false`
`4digit <= 3digit` is `true`

you can test it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcrymLsn/)

```
<h2></h2>
<form id="send" action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="x"><br/>
    <input type="text" id="y">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').submit(function(){
        var x = $('#x').val();
        var y = $("#y").val();
        if (x <= y) {
            $('h2').html("Done.");
        } else {
            $('h2').html("Sorry,not enough cash.");
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: `event` is missing in `function()`. It's `function(event)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert it to integer before you do anything, as it sorts / compares as string or something else, where `"600"` becomes greater than `"1000"`:

```
var x = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10);
var y = parseInt($("#y").val(), 10);
```

**Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h60fva4p/**

Comment: i will just pick the one who is the quickest response because two of you is correct, praveen -10:20:35 rory - 10:20:37 . too close hahah :) i hope that's fair for both of you :)

Comment: @Jayrex Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the values to integers. At the moment you're comparing strings. Also note you need to call `preventDefault()` on the `event` that's passed in to the handler function. Try this:

```
$('#send').submit(function(e) { // the 'e' parameter is the event
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10);
    var y = parseInt($("#y").val(), 10);
    $('h2').html(x <= y ? "Done." : "Sorry, not enough cash.");
});
```

Comment: i will just pick the one who is the quickest response because two of you is correct, praveen -10:20:35 rory - 10:20:37 . too close hahah :) i hope that's fair for both of you :)

Comment: That's fine, although I did fix your problem with the event ;)

Comment: @Jayrex your comment is awesome.. very Honest u r

Comment: thanks for that though. i really appreciate it a lot :). you are more far from him, let's give him a chance hahaha no offense to praveen :)

Comment: Remember to use the radix in parseInt for reasons stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @diynevala I did...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it is present at this answer, but not at some answers below.. It is easy to overlook as the radix is optional, but if forgotten, some browsers may parse the number as an Octal number - I think in the case of "0123". Just a reminder - this will save LOTS of debugging time. :)

Answer (score 3):

Please use ParseInt for Both the values:

```
var x = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10);
var y = parseInt($("#y").val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `parseInt`

```
var x = parseInt($('#x').val());
var y = parseInt($("#y").val());
```

If you are expecting decimal values on given input you can use `parseFloat()` also.

Comment: `parseInt('0x10') === 16`, remember redix

Answer (score 2):

Use `Number` to convert into number

```
var x = Number($('#x').val());
var y = Number($("#y").val());
```

Comment: Better option than parseInt, as if users get a decimal number parseInt will convert it to nearmost Integer.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#send').submit(function () {
            var x = $('#x').val();
            var y = $("#y").val();
            if (parseInt(x) <= parseInt(y)) {
                $('h2').html("Done.");
            }
            else {
                $('h2').html("Sorry,not enough cash.");
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```